# PHP - Format Date Array and Compare

Tags: php, date

Format Dates:

```
$nonzero_task_date = array_map(function($values)
            {
                return date('d-m-Y', strtotime($values));
            }, $nonzero_task_date);

            $date_arr = array_map(function($value)
            {
                return date('d-m-Y', strtotime($value));
            }, $date_arr);
```

**Date array:**

```
print_r($date_arr);

    Array
(
    [0] => 13-04-2015
    [1] => 14-04-2015
    [2] => 15-04-2015
    [3] => 16-04-2015
    [4] => 17-04-2015
    [5] => 18-04-2015
    [6] => 19-04-2015
)

print_r($nonzero_task_date );

    Array
(
    [0] => 16-04-2015
    [1] => 14-04-2015
    [2] => 13-04-2015
    [3] => 16-04-2015
    [4] => 17-04-2015
)

foreach ($date_arr as $row) {
  //$format_date = new DateTime($row);
  //$date_format = $format_date->format('d-m-Y');

   //compare dates 
  if( (in_array($row, $nonzero_task_date)) ){
    $sql = 'update query';

  }
}
```

The above code formats the date, but fails when dates are compared using `in_array()`?

Also it slow down the sql process and takes time due to number of records in DB, if date formatted in foreach loop.

Comment: Firs of all, are you sure, that process is slow because of this code? It seems, like you are trying to prematurely optimize it without proper profiling.

Comment: Yes it gets slow when I format  the date inside foreach. Formatting it before loop will help remove the unnecessary date formatting inside loop

Comment: So you are hoping to find a way format an array of dates without looping over the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to run a function over each array element before looping over it.

```
$date_arr = array_map(function($value)
{
    return date('d-m-Y', strtotime($value));
}, $date_arr);
```

Comment: Jordan Doyle: is the code applicable before `foreach` loop ? and how its different from `$format_date = new DateTime($row);
  $date_format = $format_date->format('d-m-Y');` ?

Comment: @Jordan What about array_walk() ? Can it be used in this case ?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy the code will work before the `foreach` loop and there's really not much difference between `strtotime` and `DateTime` in this case except one less object to clean up.

Comment: `$date_arr = array_map(function($value)
{
    return date('d-m-Y', strtotime($value));
}, $date_arr);`

`foreach ($date_arr as $row) {
    print_r($row); //formatted date
}` 

Is this correct ?

Comment: @AwRak `array_walk` will work in this case but I prefer `array_map` due to it not passing in a reference making it more obvious in what it's doing.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy yes, that's correct, [that code works for me](http://puu.sh/hgMtw/833f41507b.png)

Comment: @JordanDoyle it should not be - `$date_arr[] = ...`?

Comment: @JordanDoyle, it changes my existing date format. Although it does not compare two dates. Pls see my updated question

Comment: @sgt no, that would add a new value to the end of the array, `array_map` returns the new array with the lambda ran over each element

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy are you getting any errors? Is your MySQL syntax correct?

Comment: @JordanDoyle, the dates are not comparing. Changed  to `$nonzero_task_date[] = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($task_list['TASK_DATE']));` and then with your code applied before `foreach` loop I' am using ` (in_array($row, $nonzero_task_date))`

Comment: @JordanDoyle, it seems the foreach works only if `array_map` is not applied. Else the loop just do not execute

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy code you've provided works for me. See it here in action https://ideone.com/DkqvEs